# Using multiple stylesheets with WordPress

Tags: css, wordpress, themes, wordpress-theming

I'm currently creating a new WordPress theme based on the foundation them '_s'.

Could somebody explain to me how I can split up my style.css file into several to make them easier to manage? For instance, I'd like to have a layout.css, typography.css and other.css file stored within a /css folder.

How do I set this up. Presumably I need to add something to the header.php file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just include them via `<link />` elements in the `header.php` template file.

Failing that, you can always use the CSS [`@import`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/CSS/@import) function:

**theme.css**:

```
@import url("layout.css");
@import url("typography.css");

/* Other styles here: */
body {
    margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

"Just include them via  elements in the header.php template file (under or before the the main stylesheet, depending on hierarchy)."

As the first answerer said.

"Avoid the `@import` directive"

As Google Webmasters say ;)

[ https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/rtt#AvoidCssImport ]

**EDIT ↓**

However, I don't recommend using more than one stylesheet, since more stylesheets, mean more HTTP Requests and mean lower page speed performance.